# Overlay image in ImageView by border drawable

Tags: android, imageview, border, drawable

I have a border for ImageView: [image]

I want to overlay image in ImageView by this border, but i get like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by overlay image?

Comment: I want that my image to be inside this border.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't the picture of the camera inside the border as it should be?

Comment: No. Look at the border, image overlaps its.

Comment: Ok I think I might understand what you mean now. Could you post some code or XML that you used to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using FrameLayout

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:id="@+id/itemImage"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:cropToPadding="false" android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="131.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="131.5dp" android:background="@drawable/image_view_border">
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```